# ASP.NET Identity - Extend available fields of User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm struggling to show FirstName in my shared view. Please see my the code below and let me know where I got it wrong.

The AppUser class in IdentityModels has been extended to include FirstName.
In debug mode, `var claim` is null and I couldn't figure out why?

**IdentityExtensions.cs**

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static string FirstName(this IPrincipal usr)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)usr.Identity).FindFirst("FirstName");
            // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

**AppUser.cs**

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AppUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", FirstName));
            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Surname", Surname));
            return userIdentity;
        }

    }
```

In the view, I could see the method FirstName(), however it returns empty string
**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.FirstName()
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: clear cookies? login-logout? What you are doing looks good to me

Comment: @trailmax I cleared the cache, logged in and out and still cannot see any results. Weird :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CreateUserIdentityAsync` was missing. By adding it, I managed to get the FirstName and other properties I added.

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<AppUser, string>
        {
            public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(AppUser user)
            {
                return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
            }

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

simply just edit your Register Action to this

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = "MyFirstName" };
```

you have to set the value of the FirstName in your Register Action

Comment: Why would I add this in Register Action? Also I’m not using the Register Action at all in my project

Comment: put it anywhere, but you have to assign value to FirstName before you call it